# JavaScript ошибка при запросе

Tags: javascript

При запросе возникает ошибка: TypeError: "sad.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/api/issues/…" is not a function

```
     let url = "https://sad.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/api/issues/?query=Board%20Testamex%20Web:%20%7B2%20sprint%7D%20State:%20%7BNeed%20testing%7D"
(async function main() {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(proxyurl + url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            },
        });

        let result = await response.json();
        console.log(result.message);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кажется, это всего лишь ошибка ASI (https://2ality.com/2011/05/semicolon-insertion.html).

Поставьте точку с запятой после `let url = ...`, чтобы скобка на следующей строке не парсилась как начало вызова функции.